# Derangements of Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

I am trying to review a problem I answered incorrectly on a test in my Combinatorics class. The problem reads:

> Let $d(n,k)$ denote the number of derangements of length $n$ that have exactly $k$ cycles. Find a formula for $d(n,k)$. Your formula may contain one summation sign. It may also contain Stirling numbers.

Not sure how to approach this problem, as it has been a while since this exam.

Answer (score 4):

You can approach it as a straightforward inclusion-exclusion problem. There are ${n\brack k}$ permutations of $[n]$ with exactly $k$ cycles. For each $i\in[n]$ there are ${n-1}\brack{k-1}$ permutations of $[n]$ that fix $i$ and have $k-1$ other cycles. In general, if $0\le\ell\le k$, and $S$ is an $\ell$-element subset of $[n]$, there are ${n-\ell}\brack{k-\ell}$ permutations of $[n]$ that fix each element of $S$ and have a total of $k$ cycles. There are $\binom{n}\ell$ such subsets of $[n]$, so the usual inclusion-exclusion calculation tells you that

$$d(n,k)=\sum_{\ell=0}^k(-1)^\ell\binom{n}\ell{{n-\ell}\brack{k-\ell}}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianScott. I did mention inclusion exclusion in my post near the end. ;-)

Comment: @Marko: I saw the combinatorial species and didn’t read any further, I’m afraid. (I also knew exactly whose answer it was!) One of these years I’m going to have to sit down and actually learn that way of approaching these problems. Maybe if I read enough of your answers ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the very kind remark. Anyway your explanation is better than mine and probably closer to what the problem has in mind, so that we now have a varied set of comments. Yes species theory is extremely powerful but you do have to be careful with the mechanics (algebra). Wikipedia is good on this subject. It's a pleasure to work with you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I can help here even if my methodolgy probably shows up somewhat later in your course.

The combinatorial species $\mathcal{Q}$ of derangements with cycles marked is given by
$$\mathcal{Q} = \mathfrak{P}(
\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{C}_2(\mathcal{Z}) +
\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{C}_3(\mathcal{Z}) +
\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{C}_4(\mathcal{Z}) +
\cdots).$$
This translates into generating functions like so:
$$Q(z,u) = \exp\left(u\frac{z^2}{2}+u\frac{z^3}{3}+u\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)
= \exp\left(-uz + u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$
This becomes
$$Q(z, u) = \exp\left(-uz\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^u.$$
Switching to series this yields
$$Q(z, u) = \left(\sum_{q=0}^\infty (-u)^q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
\sum_{q=0}^\infty {q+u-1\choose q} z^q.$$
Extracting coefficients from this we get
$$n! [z^n] Q(z, u) =
n! \sum_{q=0}^n {q+u-1\choose q} \frac{(-u)^{n-q}}{(n-q)!}.$$
This is our first formula and it can be used to calculate $d_{n,k}$ quite effectively. The problem asks for Stirling numbers, however, so we provide a second formula. Recall that
$$n! [z^n] [u^k] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^u
= \left[n\atop k\right].$$
Taking into account the exponential term in $Q(z,u)$, we get
$$n! [z^n] [u^k] Q(z, u)
= n! \sum_{q=0}^k \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} [z^{n-q}] [u^{k-q}] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^u
\\= \sum_{q=0}^k (-1)^q\frac{n!}{q!(n-q)!} (n-q)! [z^{n-q}] [u^{k-q}] 
\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^u
\\=  \sum_{q=0}^k (-1)^q {n\choose q} \left[n-q\atop k-q\right].$$
Here is a Maple program that can be used to verify the above formulas. The second formula represents inclusion-exclusion, with the variable $q$ counting the number of fixed points.

```
with(combinat):

dnk :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local res, p, dc, nonfix, lens;

    res := 0;

    for p in permute(n) do
        dc := convert(p, 'disjcyc');
        lens := map(nops, dc);

        if add(lens[q], q=1..nops(lens)) = n then
            if nops(lens) = k then
                res := res+1;
            fi;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;
```